# What are internal lists in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

In one interview, interviewer asked that what are **Internal lists** and **External lists** in sharpeoint.
External lists means when we create any list by any of the templates like announcements, calender,Custom list etc. (Correct me if I am wrong.)

Then what are the internal lists in sharepoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External list is the list which you create by using any data source. For example list created by using BCS is external list.

Internal list is the list which we created internally(in our site) by using UI or VS2010.